# Set multiple values for subset of Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say my data frame df has two columns: block, trial. There are 10 trials per each block. Now I want to create a new column "response" from a list "my_response". I can't seem to do something like below:

```
my_response = [1,5,2,4,3,1,4,2,3,4]
df.loc[df['block'] == 0, 'response'] = my_response
```

I know that I can set values if it's a scalar value

```
df.loc[df['block'] == 0, 'response'] = 1
```

Is there any way I can put a list of values for the subset of dataframe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and a dictionary

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(block=[0, 0, 1, 1], trial=[0, 1, 0, 1]))

my_response = {0: [1,5,2,4,3,1,4,2,3,4]}

df.assign(response=df.block.map(my_response))

   block  trial                        response
0      0      0  [1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4]
1      0      1  [1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4]
2      1      0                             NaN
3      1      1                             NaN
```

You can even pass a default empty list

```
df.assign(response=df.block.map(lambda x: my_response.get(x, [])))

   block  trial                        response
0      0      0  [1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4]
1      0      1  [1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4]
2      1      0                              []
3      1      1                              []
```